# Selecting from database using SQLite - 'No such column'

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In my application I want to bring up modules depending on who is logged into the application.

This works perfectly if I use test data such as simple data, eg, 1 as username and 1 as password, however when I use real life test data, eg C343, it throws the error saying there is no such column, even though in logcat it shows it in the database.

Here is how I select the information from the database:

in **DB.java**

```
public class DB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int db_version = 1;  
    //Student Table
    public static final String Table = "Students";      
    public static final String Student_ID = "Student_ID";
    public static final String Student_Name = "Student_Name";
    public static final String Student_Password = "Student_Password";
    public static final String Student_Gender = "gender";
    public static final String Student_Age = "age";
    public static final String Student_Course = "course";
    public static final String Modules1 = "modules1";
    public static final String Modules2 = "modules2";
    public static final String Modules = "modules";
    public static final String CNumber = "CNumber";
    //Modules Table
    public static final String Table2 = "Modules";  
    public static final String Module_ID = "moduleid";
    public static final String Module_Name = "modulename";
    public static final String Module_Lectureroom = "modulelectureroom";
    public static final String Module_Seminarroom = "moduleseminarroom";
    public static final String Module_Lecturer = "modulelecturer";
    public static final String Module_Group = "modulegroup";
    public static final String Module_Lecturetime = "modulelecturetime";
    public static final String Module_Seminartime = "moduleseminartime";
    public static final String Module_Lecturedate = "modulelecturedate";
    public static final String Module_Seminardate = "moduleseminardate";

    public boolean checker = false;
    public DB(Context context) {
        super(context, tableColumns.Database, null, db_version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Table);
        Log.d("DB", "Creating table...");   
        //Students Table
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + Table + "(" + 
                Student_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +      
                Student_Name + " TEXT, " +
                Student_Password + " TEXT, " +
                Student_Age + " TEXT, " +
                Student_Gender + " TEXT, " +              
                Student_Course + " TEXT, " +
                Modules1 + " TEXT, " +
                Modules2 + " TEXT, " +
                Modules + " TEXT, " +
                CNumber + " TEXT)");
        Log.d("DB", "Student Table Created");
        //Modules Table
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Table2);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + Table2 + "(" + 
                Module_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                Module_Name + " TEXT, " +
                Module_Lectureroom + " TEXT, " +
                Module_Seminarroom + " TEXT, " +
                Module_Lecturer + " TEXT, " +
                Module_Group + " TEXT, " +            
                Module_Lecturetime + " TEXT, " +
                Module_Seminartime + " TEXT, " +
                Module_Lecturedate + " TEXT, " +
                Module_Seminardate + " TEXT)");
        Log.d("DB", "Module Table Created");
            }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Table);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Table2);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean Login(String username, String password) throws SQLException
    {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Table + " WHERE CNumber=? AND Student_Password=?", new String[]{username,password});        
    if (mCursor != null) {
    if(mCursor.getCount() > 0)
    {
    checker = true;
    return true;
    }
    }
    return false;
    }


    public void createstudents()
    {
        insertStudent("Matt", "123", 22, "Male", "Computing", "Digital Security", "Mod2", "Mod3", "C3438525");
        insertStudent("Charlie", "Test", 19, "Male", "Sport Science", "Biomech Analysis", "Meas & Eval for Phsio", "Prof Dev", "C33429960");
        insertStudent("Amber", "Test", 20, "Female", "Travel & Tourism", "Work based learning", "Sustainable Tourism", "Tourism Operations", "C3399607");
        insertStudent("1", "1", 1, "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "2");
        insertStudent("Test", "Test", 2, "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "C343Test");
        Log.d("Students", "Created");       
    }

    public void createmodules()
    {
        insertModules("Digital Security", "CAG05", "JG202", "Michael Kemp", "A", "15:00PM", "11:00AM", "Tuesday", "Tuesday");
        Log.d("Modules", "Created");
    }

    public void reset(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Table);
        onCreate(db);   
    }

    public List<tableStudents> getData() {
        List<tableStudents> studentList = new ArrayList<tableStudents>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + Table;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                tableStudents student = new tableStudents();
                student.name = cursor.getString(1);
                student.password = cursor.getString(2);
                student.age = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3));
                student.gender = cursor.getString(4);            
                student.course = cursor.getString(5);
                student.modules = cursor.getString(6);             
                student.modules1 = cursor.getString(7);
                student.modules2 = cursor.getString(8);
                student.cnumber = cursor.getString(9);
                studentList.add(student);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return contact list
        return studentList;     
    }

    public List<tableStudents> getStudentsModules(String username) {
        List<tableStudents> studentModules = new ArrayList<tableStudents>();

        // Select All Query depending on who is logged in.      
        String selectQuery = "SELECT " + Modules1 + ", " + Modules2 + ", " + Modules + " FROM " + Table + " WHERE " + CNumber + " = " + username;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                tableStudents student = new tableStudents();                
                student.modules = cursor.getString(0);             
                student.modules1 = cursor.getString(1);
                student.modules2 = cursor.getString(2);       
                studentModules.add(student);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return contact list
        return studentModules;      
    }

    public List<tableModules> getModules() {
        List<tableModules> moduleList = new ArrayList<tableModules>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + Table2;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                tableModules module = new tableModules();
                module.modulename = cursor.getString(1);
                module.modulelectureroom = cursor.getString(2);
                module.moduleseminarroom = cursor.getString(3);
                module.modulelecturer = cursor.getString(4);             
                module.modulegroup = cursor.getString(5);
                module.modulelecturetime = cursor.getString(6);            
                module.moduleseminartime = cursor.getString(7);
                module.modulelecturedate = cursor.getString(8);
                module.moduleseminardate = cursor.getString(9);
                moduleList.add(module);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return contact list
        return moduleList;      
    }

    public boolean insertStudent(String name, String password, int age, String gender, String course, String modules, String modules1, String modules2, String CNumb) {     
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();  
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();       
        contentValues.put(Student_Name, name);    
        contentValues.put(Student_Gender, gender);
        contentValues.put(Student_Age, age);      
        contentValues.put(Student_Password, password);
        contentValues.put(Student_Course, course);
        contentValues.put(Modules, modules);
        contentValues.put(Modules1, modules1);
        contentValues.put(Modules2, modules2);
        contentValues.put(CNumber, CNumb);   
        db.insert(Table, null, contentValues);
        Log.d("DB", "Students Inserted Successfully");
        return true;
    }

    public boolean insertModules(String modulename, String modulelectureroom, String moduleseminarroom, String modulelecturer, String modulegroup, String modulelecturetime, String moduleseminartime, String modulelecturedate, String moduleseminardate) {        
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();  
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();       
        contentValues.put(Module_Name, modulename);   
        contentValues.put(Module_Lectureroom, modulelectureroom);
        contentValues.put(Module_Seminarroom, moduleseminarroom);     
        contentValues.put(Module_Lecturer, modulelecturer);
        contentValues.put(Module_Group, modulegroup);
        contentValues.put(Module_Lecturetime, modulelecturetime);
        contentValues.put(Module_Seminartime, moduleseminartime);
        contentValues.put(Module_Lecturedate, modulelecturedate);
        contentValues.put(Module_Seminardate, moduleseminardate);    
        db.insert(Table2, null, contentValues);
        Log.d("DB", "Modules Inserted Successfully");
        return true;
    }

}
```

and it is then called in **MainActivity.java**, saving the modules to strings.

```
List<tableStudents> studentModules = db.getStudentsModules(sessionName);            
            for (tableStudents session: studentModules)
            {
                //Save modules to string
                String module1 = session.modules.toString();
                String module2 = session.modules1.toString();
                String module3 = session.modules2.toString();           
            }
```

This is the **Logcat** for when I log in with C343Test as the username and Test as the password:

```
02-22 00:24:15.214: D/Username+PW Combos(2593): Username: C343Test Password: Test
02-22 00:24:15.214: D/Digital Security(2593): Michael Kemp
02-22 00:24:15.302: E/SQLiteLog(2593): (1) no such column: C343Test
02-22 00:24:15.322: D/AndroidRuntime(2593): Shutting down VM
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593): Process: com.example.project, PID: 2593
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.project/com.example.project.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: C343Test (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT modules1, modules2, modules FROM Students WHERE CNumber = C343Test
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2989)
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3020)
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: C343Test (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT modules1, modules2, modules FROM Students WHERE CNumber = C343Test
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at com.example.project.DB.getStudentsModules(DB.java:160)
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at com.example.project.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:79)
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1257)
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6076)
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2978)
02-22 00:24:15.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: You might want learn to use SQLiteQueryBuilder instead of trying to build the string yourself with correct quoting.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to increase the db version if you have modified the tables in any way, otherwise onUpdate will not be called. And you have to use quotes if you are doing string comparision:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT " + Modules1 + ", " + Modules2 + ", " + Modules + " FROM " + Table + " WHERE " + CNumber + " = \"" + username + "\"";
```

Comment: if you have modified the table after you have created it for the first time, have you increased the db version number? otherwise SQLLite will not generate a new version of your database

Comment: No I haven't. Should I change it to 2? I don't see how this would affect the query though.

Comment: when you have added columns, after you have created the tables in a previous run, then the new columns will not be added to your model if you not increase the number of your database. OnUprade will not be called

Comment: Awesome, increasing the database version works. I will select your answer. Just wondering if you know a way to stop the database creating multiple versions of the same data? Every time the activity is refreshed it creates another set. I am just calling db.creatstudents() and db.createmodules in oncreate, do you know a way round this?

Comment: well you can implement check functions in your databaseclass and check if the data is already inserted, but its hard to tell without code, maybe make it a new question ;)